# What's the advantage of using bra-ket notation over inner-product notation?

Tags: notation, inner-products

Both notations look pretty similar, and appear similar when undergo algebraic operations. Apart from personal taste (aesthetics) concerning commas ($\langle \phantom{\cdot},\phantom{\cdot} \rangle$) vs. pipes ($\langle \phantom{\cdot}\mid \phantom{\cdot}\rangle$), what is (are) the practical advantage(s) of using the [bra-ket notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) over the [inner-product notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition)?

Comment: bras and kets can be useful to denote stuff outside of the Hilbert space and living in the rigged Hilbert space, like the "eigenvectors" of an operator with continuous spectrum.

Comment: They are basically aliases of each other, except that, as in the comment above, bra-kets are more elastic/permissive and extend outside strict definitions. For example, $\langle x| y\rangle= \delta(x-y)$, etc.